# How to implement weekly update leaderboard?

Tags: android, time, android-sqlite, leaderboard

I would like to implement a leaderboard on the website, which will show users who did particular action (for simplification, let's say - button click) more often during the previous week.
I am trying to understand what is the best approach to count number of actions and send it to the server.

The first question I see is time difference. How to count 'previous week' on the client side?

The second question is how to send the data to the server? I don't care too much about data security, so it could be send as open text (I am OK that some users may hack that). But I am care about **when** the data should be sent. Per current synchronization process, the data is sent to/from the server when user is online and not more than once per day. If I follow the same approach, then leaders could be identified let's say on Wednesday - once week is passed and 2 days are given for the data sending (if counting happens on the client side).

The third question is how to store this data on the client side. SQLite looks too complicated for this simple task.

Any ideas how to deal with this task?

Comment: Have you consider play service , http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html

Comment: @TomerMor, no, I haven't considered it. Does it allow to export information (since leaderboard should be displayed on my own site)? Will it allow to send the data from the webserver, not from the android application (since android app is just one way to be included into the board)?